# Why does my server gets requests for domains that are not mapped to my IP

Tags: networking

As title states ... Why does my server (nginx) gets requests for domains that are not mapped to my IP?

I've split my nginx logs to create a log file for each website that it processes and i've noticed that it has created logs for sites that do not point to me.

Some of those include :

- google.pl
- ebay.com
- booking.com
- 126.com
- so.com
- stumpleupon.com

and bunch of others that I haven't heard of.

Can someone explain why do users end up on my server instead of where they have to go?

Comment: DNS cache poisoning or host files, or their own malicious dns server, etc.. You sure they're not referrers though?

Comment: It is most likely the internet background noise of people probing systems for vulnerabilities but show us some relevant log entries.

Comment: Simple `curl http://your-host.com -H "Host: anydomain.com"` will do the trick.

Comment: One of the vulnerabilities commonly probed for is if your server is configured incorrectly as an open proxy. Probes for that appear as `GET www.example.com HTTP/1.1` in your web server access logs. Those requests should result in an error, a successful status (e.g. 200) would normally be bad.

Comment: @HBruijn I have seen apache process that kind of request on its own without forwarding. That would result in success without actually being an open proxy, so a 200 in the log does not have to be bad.